# How to force users create host-only VirtualBox VMs

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, nat

Managing many users within a security-strict network makes a VM a bad option. If the admin allows the installation of VirtualBox throughout the network, how can admins force users to setup host-only VMs?

The VirtualBox Manager needs admin rights to install a Host-Only Adaptor, but does not need admin rights to enable NATing on a Virtual network adaptor. My use-case is just the opposite; I need to block NATing.

Is there a post-installation step to disable NATing, uninstall the service, or simply hide it from the VB Manager?

Environment:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Oracle's VirtualBox

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: Why would you allow the installation of Virtualization Solutions in the first place in this scenario?

Comment: Some users really need to have a VM, for tools compatibility, testing on other platforms .. etc. But they should not be allowed to access the network.

Comment: Why not offer those VMs from a centralized service rather than on the users computer? You could also check the [virtual box manual section 9.20 Locking down the virtual box GUI](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#guitweaks). Though this could probably be reversed by using vboxmanage I'd guess.